# How can I rewrite URL paths to query strings using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I get $_GET requests from each existing PHP file from directory listings in my URL, like this:

```
# Scenario 1: Assuming existence of file.php
    URL like: /path/to/file/v1/v2/v3 ...
    Act like: /path/to/file.php?v1&v2&v3
              or
              /path/to/file.php?query=[v1,v2,v3 ...]
    HTTP GET: array(v1 => null,v2 => null, v3 => null, ...) or array(v1, v2, v3)
    or
    HTTP GET: array(query => [v1,v2,v3])

# Scenario 2: Assuming existence of file.php
    URL like: /path/to/file/k1/v1/k2/v2 ...
    Act like: /path/to/file.php?k1=v1&k2=v2 ...
    HTTP GET: array(k1 => v1, k2 => v2, ...)
```

Since I'm not familiar enough with Apache configs, hope someone could help me with that.

Just note that I already have these codes for other reasons in my .htaccess file:

```
# To remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# To remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ (.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To check whether the PHP file exists and set it back internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L]

# To redirect /index to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't get to remove questions just because you got an answer. This site is for questions and answers of permanent interest. It isn't a free help desk.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use mod-rewrite for redirecting based on query string:

Make sure in your httpd.conf, the following lines are uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And here is an example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)thiscontent=2660(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?applications/newWeb/www/index\.php$ http://www.example.come/index.php/folder1/foler2/folder-resources? [L,R=301]
```